# Length of array in JSON object is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am retrieving JSON data from a PHP file like so:

```
$.getJSON('fresh_posts.php',function(data){
    global_save_json = data.freshcomments;
    var countPosts = data.freshposts;
    var howManyPosts = countPosts.length;
```

I need to get the length of the first main array in the object, but there is an issue.

`howManyPosts` is returning `undefined`.

The JSON object from `freshposts.php` looks like this:

```
{ 
    "freshposts":{

         // two example posts with ID 5 and 2

        "5": {
            "id":"5",
            "image":"link.jpg",
            "submitter":"4322309",
            "views":"3"
        },
        "2": {
            "id":"2",
            "image":"link.jpg",
            "submitter":"4322309",
            "views":"5"
        }
    },

    // now each comment tied to the posts

    "freshcomments":{
        "2": [{
            "id":"1",
            "submitter":"submitter",
            "time":"2435657",
            "comment":"comment",
            "score":"10",
            "postid":"2"
        },
        {
            "id":"2",
            "submitter":"submitter",
            "time":"2435657",
            "comment":"comment",
            "score":"10",
            "postid":"2"
        }
    ],
        "5": [{
            "id":"3",
            "submitter":"submitter",
            "time":"2435657",
            "comment":"comment",
            "score":"10",
            "postid":"5"
        }]
    }
}
```

What is causing this?

Comment: `data.freshposts` isn't an array.

Comment: Ah, it's an object? How would I get how many elements are in the object then?

Comment: `Object.keys(theobject).length` might do what you want.

Comment: What do you mean 'returning undefined'? It's a variable

Comment: Better yet, make it an array, rather than hacking around the fact that you're returning a semantically incorrect data type.

Comment: @ValentinWaeselynck when I console log it. Kevin B I will try that

Comment: Note that the id property in your objects are redundant if you're using them as keys. so, either you don't need the id property, or, you don't need this as an object and can safely transition to using an array instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something like:

```
$.getJSON('fresh_posts.php',function(data){
    global_save_json = data.freshcomments;
    var countPosts = Object.keys(data.freshposts).length;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

"freshposts" is not an array it's an object:

```
"freshposts": { ... }
```

It should look like this:

```
"freshposts": [ ... ]
```